# Is it possible for cumulocity to subscribe with an MQTT broker as a subscriber to pull data?

Tags: cumulocity

We have our data available in the MQTT broker. Instead of sending the data via an MQTT client is it possible for the cumulocity tenant to subscribe to our MQTT broker?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box.

You would need to implement some kind of integrator that subscribes to your broker and publishes on Cumulocity (or inputs the data via HTTP)